Uniqueness of 1st order linear ODE with step discontinuities in driving function
Consider the following first order ODE initial value problem with a discontinuous driving function composed of step functions:
$$y'(t) + y(t) = u_1(t) - u_2(t)$$
$$y(0) = 0$$
$$u_a(t) \equiv
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } t < a, \\
1 & \text{if } t > a
\end{cases}$$
My book has the following solution:
$$y(t) = \left[1 - e^{-(t-1)} \right] u_1(t) - \left[ 1 - e^{-(t-2)} \right] u_2(t)$$
I think that the following, more general solution is correct, however:
$$y(t) = \left[ 1 + c_1 e^{(-t + c_2)} \right]  u_1(t) - \left[ 1 +  c_3 e^{(-t + c_4)} \right] u_2(t)$$
$$c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4 \text{ are real numbers}$$
Two questions:

Is my solution correct, or is my book's solution the only correct solution (since it is the unique solution)?

The theorems in my books don't seem to guarantee a unique solution, since the driving function is discontinuous. Is there a theorem that addresses uniqueness of solutions in this class of problem?



You are correct in that ordinary ODE theory only applies to the case of a continuous right side. It is thus necessary to employ an extended understanding of what a solution is. One certainly wants to retain that a solution is a continuous function. It would be nice if it would also stay a continuously differentiable function.
This is indeed possible, even with keeping the uniqueness property, in this special situation. On each of the intervals $(-\infty,1]$, $[1,2]$, $[2,\infty)$ the right side is continuous, the equation (trivially) linear and thus a solution exists and is bounded on the whole interval. Values at the boundary thus exist and can serve as initial values for the next interval. The such obtained pieces over each interval can be composed into an unique continuously differentiable function over all of $\Bbb R$. This is the reference solution you gave.
Your solution with the many constants is generally not continuous at the interval boundaries. While it is a solution for each interval separately. it is not a solution as a function over $\Bbb R$.

If I understand you correctly, what you're saying (without saying it directly) is that differential equations frequently model real world phenomena. In a real word application, we'll never be able to generate a perfect square wave function. The driving function will be continuous, and the solution to that problem should converge upon the solution to the idealized problem. The real word approximation will converge upon the book's answer, so that's the correct answer.

I'm not sure that I said that much, but it is of course correct and lead to the generalized solution theory of Fillippov. I'm just saying that there is a existence-and-uniqueness theory for ODE that can only applied to pieces of the present problem, but that the pieces assemble to a unique solution. One could make a general claim about ODE that get a piecewise continuous function of time added.

I added my comment because I was trying to figure out the motivation for your saying "One certainly wants to retain that a solution is a continuous function. It would be nice if it would also stay a continuously differentiable function." Why exactly does one want that? If the solution is not unique, why would we try to change our standard of what unique means. To me, the obvious answer is that we want a solution that is the convergence of a real world scenario, where the driving function is actually continuous, instead of discontinuous.

One want that because that is rather minimalist: Given is an equation about a function and its first derivative, so solution candidates will need to be differentiable functions. All the rest is due to the fact that the DE is almost regular.
